# Array Slicing Numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

```
r =  np.arange(36)
r.resize((6,6))

output:
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
```

**My questions are:**

1. How can I extract a sub-array from the full matrix?

**Example:**

```
 [[14 15],                                                                            
  [20 21]]
```

2. What the difference between `resize` and `reshape` syntax in `numpy`?

Comment: Both questions in your post would have given you the answer when put into a search engine.

Comment: Use `reshape`. `resize` is rarely used.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can extract the desired portion of the array by `sliceing` operation:

```
r =  np.arange(36)
r = r.reshape((6, 6))    
r[2:4, 2:4]
```

2. 

- [`numpy.resize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html) receives the `numpy.array` to be resized and `new_shape` (which is of type `int` or `tuple` of `ints`), that represent the shape of the resized array, and returns the resized `numpy.array`.
- [`numpy.reshape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) receives the `numpy.array` to be reshaped and a `newshape` (which is again of type `int` or `tuple` of `ints`), that represent the desired shape of the output array, and returns the reshaped `numpy.array`.

The main difference between the two methods, is that `resize` pads the output to match the desired shape, while `reshape` will throw an error if the requested shape does not fit the data.

**For example:**

```
r =  np.arange(36)
r = r.reshape((6, 1))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-165-36ecb32eda6e> in <module>
      1 r =  np.arange(36)
----> 2 r = r.reshape((6, 1))
      3 r[2:4, 2:4]

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36 into shape (6,1)
```

while if you'd use `resize` it will output the desired array:

```
r =  np.arange(36)
r.resize((6,1))
r


array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5]])
```